# How To Sequentially Display div's With Different Time Intervals For Each

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good Afternoon All

We've been able to get a basic version of this working with a single time interval in javascript

```
    time = 10000; // 10 Seconds
    var counter = 0;
    divs = $('#div1, #div2, #div3, #div4, #div5');
    function showDiv () {
    divs.hide() // hide all divs
        .filter(function (index) { return index == counter % 5; }) 
    // figure out correct div to show
        .fadeIn(300, "linear"); // and show it
        counter++;
        if (counter > 5 ){
            counter = 1; //Reset Counter
        }
   }; // function to loop through divs and show correct div
   showDiv(); // show first div  

   setInterval(function(){ showDiv(); }, time); // do this every 10 seconds 
   });
```

What I'd like to do is cause the intervals to be different on each of the div times

Like div1 & div2 play for 10 seconds and the others play for 5 seconds

I was able to get the logic working to see if the time had changed based upon which div was displaying but could not get "time" to update from one value to another

I've been reading that using setInterval() does not allow for changing of a variable value once it's been loaded.
There were some suggestions to use setTimeout() but I could not figure it out

Anyone with a suggestion?

Thanks~

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using setInterval you can do the same thing using setTimeout() to call the function again from within itself. This allows determining intervals per instance based on counter

```
   time = 10000; // 10 Seconds
   var counter = 0;
   divs = $('#div1, #div2, #div3, #div4, #div5');

   function showDiv() {

     // hide all divs, filter current index, and fadeIn
       divs.hide().eq(counter).fadeIn(300, "linear"); 

       counter++;
       if (counter > 5) {
           counter = 1; //Reset Counter
       }

       // do it again       
       var delay = counter > 1 ? time / 2 : time
       setTimeout(showDiv, delay);



   }; // function to loop through divs and show correct div
   showDiv(); // show first div
```

Also streamlined using filter(fn) and replaced with `eq()`

Answer (score 0):

Correct, the interval for `setInterval` cannot be changed once it is started. You'll need to use `setTimeout` to make the interval different each time. The idea is to call `setTimeout` again in the callback passed to `setTimeout`, thereby creating a chain of calls. This is a common pattern.

```
// Different timeouts for each div
var times = [10000, 10000, 5000, 5000, 5000];
var counter = 0;
function showDiv() {
  // Show the div immediately
  divs.hide().eq(counter).fadeIn(300, 'linear');
  // Cycle the counter
  counter = (counter + 1) % divs.length;
  // Set the delay for the next callback
  setTimeout(showDiv, times[counter]);
}
// Start the chain of calls
showDiv();
```

Answer (score 0):

A hearty thank you and a brewski to both...

I ended up taking the best of both and here's what I'm now using

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function () {
 // Different timeouts for each div
 var times = [30000, 30000, 10000, 10000, 5000];
 var counter = 0;
 divs = $('#div1, #div2, #div3, #div4, #div5');
 function showDiv() {
 // hide all divs, filter current index, and fadeIn
 divs.hide().eq(counter).fadeIn(300, "linear"); 
 // set time out duration from array of times 
 setTimeout(showDiv, times[counter]);
 // cycle the counter     
 counter = (counter + 1) % divs.length;
 }; 
 showDiv(); // show first div    
 });
 </script>
```